# Generic DAO Hibernate Java

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, generics, crud

I'm trying to understand Generic DAO's at their most basic level.  I've got the basic CRUD methods created in the DAO Here:

```
public interface ObjectDAO <T>{

boolean insert(T t);

boolean update(int id, T t);



boolean delete(int id);

T retrieveByID(int id);

List<T> retrieveAll();



}
```

However, I cannot figure out how to get the id for the class that I pass into the ObjectDAOImpl. Here is the implementation:

```
public class ImplObjectDAO<T> implements ObjectDAO<T>{

Session session;

public ImplObjectDAO() {

    session= SessionSingleton.getInstance();
}

@Override
public boolean insert(T t){

        try{

        session.beginTransaction();

        session.save(t);

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        }
        catch(HibernateException he){

            he.printStackTrace();
            return false;
    }   
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean update(int id, T t) {

    try{

        session.beginTransaction();




        session.update(t);

        session.getTransaction().commit();

        return true;
        }
        catch(HibernateException he){
            he.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        catch(NullPointerException np){
            np.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
}


public boolean delete(int id){



    return true;

}

@Override
public <T> retrieveByID(int id){

    return T;
}

@Override
public List<T> retrieveAll(){
    return new ArrayList<T>(objectSet);

}


}
```

So if i pass an object like the employee class that I've created. The insert method works fine.  But once it's been inserted into the database, how do I get the id of the Entity so that I can do things like update, or delete, or retrieve? I am not understanding. Any help is appreciated.

Here is the entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Employee_Records")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private int eID;

@Column(name="EMP_NAME", length=20)
private String empName;

@Column(name="EMPLOYEE_AGE")
private int empAge;

public Employee(){
    eID= 0;
    empName="temp";
    empAge=0;
}

public Employee(int eID, String empName, int empAge) {
    this.eID = eID;
    this.empName = empName;
    this.empAge = empAge;
}

public int geteID() {
    return eID;
}

public void seteID(int eID) {
    this.eID = eID;
}

public String getEmpName() {
    return empName;
}

public void setEmpName(String empName) {
    this.empName = empName;
}

public int getEmpAge() {
    return empAge;
}

public void setEmpAge(int empAge) {
    this.empAge = empAge;
}



@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee ID=" + eID + ", Employee Name=" + empName + ", Employee    Age="
            + empAge;
}
}
```

Comment: Is that Session class from hibernate? If so, i usually use this sort of codes `Session sess = getSession();
IdentifierLoadAccess byId = sess.byId(persistentClass);
T entity = (T) byId.load(id);
sess.update(entity);
sess.delete(entity);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you want to retrieve the id of the object you just inserted. You can actually get the return value of the `save` method you just called.

So, in the example code, instead of return true when you `save` the object, you can return the id of the object instead.

you can check the example [here](http://www.journaldev.com/3481/hibernate-save-vs-saveorupdate-vs-persist-vs-merge-vs-update-explanation-with-examples).